# React full stack app deploy to Google App Engine with error webpack: not found

Tags: reactjs, webpack, gcloud

everyone. I try to deploy Reack full stack app from https://github.com/crsandeep/simple-react-full-stack
And it doesn't work. I read too many posts about deploying react to gcloud but there are simple apps and not full stack apps.

my packege.json, I took it from git

```
{
  "name": "simple-react-full-stack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Boilerplate to build a full stack web application using React, Node.js, Express and Webpack.",
  "main": "src/server/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "npm run build && node src/server/index.js",
    "client": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --devtool inline-source-map --hot",
    "server": "nodemon src/server/index.js",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
  "author": "Sandeep Raveesh",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "concurrently": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.7.0",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.3"
  }
}
```

my app.yaml I took it from google

```
env: flex 
runtime: nodejs
```

I run in terminal

```
gcloud beta app deploy
```

And I have error

```
Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.                                                                                                                                             
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] 
Application startup error:

> simple-react-full-stack@1.0.0 prestart /app
> npm run bundle


> simple-react-full-stack@1.0.0 bundle /app
> webpack --config webpack.config.js

sh: 1: webpack: not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! simple-react-full-stack@1.0.0 bundle: `webpack --config webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the simple-react-full-stack@1.0.0 bundle script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-12-04T18_45_03_238Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! simple-react-full-stack@1.0.0 prestart: `npm run bundle`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the simple-react-full-stack@1.0.0 prestart script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-12-04T18_45_03_252Z-debug.log
```

I don't understand what it need, I tried to add "npm install" and it doesn't work too.
How fix it?

Comment: did you run $ `npm update` over at gcloud? I had a problem lately with a recent out of date support content there.   Why $ `gcloud beta app deploy` and not simply $ `gcloud app deploy` ?

Comment: Ok thakns, I tried to add `npm update` to `"start": "npm update && npm run build && node src/server/index.js",`. And I have same error `webpack: not found`

Comment: I started to use `gcloud beta app deploy` after reading one post about this bug. But it doesn't help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [community tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/appengine-nodejs-webpack) you can follow, get everything working as described first and then start making the desired edits.

Please make sure you are following the steps of "[Preparing the app](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/appengine-nodejs-webpack#preparing_the_app)" section, as it seems like you are missing on of the mentioned steps.

```
npm init

npm install --save webpack express pug
```

As well as modifying package.json to include:

```
"scripts": {
  "bundle": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
  "prestart": "npm run bundle"
}
```

Also note that:

> Webpack must be listed in the dependencies of the package.json file,
>   as by default devDependencies are not installed when the app is
>   deployed to Google App Engine.

Also keep in mind that `gcloud beta app deploy` is still in **BETA** and may have changes without notice. So for what you are trying to achieve there is no need for using beta. Instead simply use `gcloud app deploy`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it